# Tools for managing the configuration of multiple servers?

Tags: configuration, chef-infra

I've been looking at OpsCode's Chef, which seems pretty cool. I was wondering if anyone else had encountered useful tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic is `cfengine`. It's been around forever.

Answer (score 0):

CFEngine has indeed been around forever, but the newest version (CFEngine 3) is a complete rewrite from previous versions. The policy language in CF3 is redesigned to make it more consistent and extensible. There's also now, if you are so inclined, a commercial version that has a nice graphical user interface and other enhancements.

There's a whole lot of information about CFEngine at http://cfengine.com/tech

(disclaimer: I work at CFEngine AS)